# Prove for the theorem "Every non deterministic Turing maching has an equivalent deterministic Turing machine"

Tags: turing-machines

I know that a Deterministic TM single tape has an equivalent Deterministic TM multiple tape, but I can't get how a Deterministic TM multiple tape can simulate a non-deterministic TM(The mecanisme).

Regards,
Thank You

Comment: Hint: given a non-deterministic Turing machine $D$ construct a deterministic Turing machine $T$ that systematically explores the states of all possible computation paths of $D$, in breadth-first search order, until the accepting state is found or all states are exhausted (in this latter case, reject). Also notice that if $D$ does not halt (that is there is no accepting path and at least one infinite computation path), then $T$ will also not halt.

Comment: So the deterministic turing machine T has tape for the input, tape for the enumeration and tape for the id of breadth level,of non-deterministic turing machine, from which it search? Mechanism : for a given input, a given breadth level,  simulate. Am I right?